# Como solucionar problema de xdg-utils en linux mint al iniciar Intellij?

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, linux-mint

Tengo recien instalado Linux mint y tengo el siguiente problema '*unfortunately xdg-utils seem to be unavailable on your system*', esto ocurre cuando recien instalé intellij y lo ejecuto, no encuentro solución, ni se porque ocurre, con Ubuntu esto no me pasa

Comment: Has probado instalar estas herramientas: `sudo apt-get install xdg-utils` ?

Comment: Si, dice que ya están instalados, no veo por donde hallar el problema

Comment: Pude solucionarlo sacando la opción de crear un shortcut en el escritorio y luego siguiendo los pasos.

Comment: Hola a Cuales pasos Te refieres?

Comment: Al momento de la instalación te pregunta si queres crear un shortcut en el escritorio, hay que desmarcar esa opción, ya que linux no me lo permitió, a pesar de haber instalado las herramientas xdg-utils. Los próximos pasos son para la configuracón de intellij, para elegir el tipo de theme y unos pasos mas. Luego la instalación se hace normalmente. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Tuve el mismo problema con el flatpack que provee Linux Mint 19.3. y, tal como dijo @Yaz, este problema se soluciona **desmarcando la opción "crear un shortcut en el escritorio"** en el asistente de inicio.